# Rectangle object not visible after using move() method: Canvas- Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Okk, okk, so, I'm new in Tkinter (Although not much as I already have built 3 games in it), here's my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, Main_Frame):
        Main_Frame.title("Paddle")
        Main_Frame.geometry("300x300+630+150")
        self.Y_Position = 288
        self.Can = Canvas(Main_Frame, height = 300, width = 300)
        self.Can.pack()
        self.paddle = self.Can.create_rectangle(0, 288, 90, 288, width = 15, fill = "blue")
        self.Can.bind("<Button-1>", self.Move_Paddle)
    def Move_Paddle(self, event):
        self.X_Position = event.x
        self.Can.move(self.paddle, self.X_Position, self.Y_Position)
Window = Tk()
Class = Paddle(Window)
Window.mainloop()
```

Now, I have a couple of problems here:
**Number 1:**
The rectangle created in the Canvas does not take the "Blue" color (nor any other).
**Number 2:** *(Bigger for me)*
The rectangle created goes invisible (I don't know where, I even tried to find it after Maximizing the Main_Frame), but I couldn't find it anywhere.
Though I prefer the easiest answer possible but any answer is acceptable.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your rectangle is one (or maybe zero) pixel height with border width 15, so the outline color (default to black if not specified) is shown instead of the fill color.  Set outline color to blue as well:

```py
self.paddle = self.Can.create_rectangle(0, 288, 90, 288, width=15, fill="blue", outline="blue")
```

Second the arguments to `move()` are deltas, not absolute.  Use `moveto()` instead:

```py
self.Can.moveto(self.paddle, self.X_Position, self.Y_Position)
```

Comment: Ohh, that worked, as I wanted. Thank you so much!